# Help with wordpress thesis theme customization

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, wordpress-thesis-theme

I'm trying to customize thesis theme of wordpress. I've done most of the things by using custom_functions.php, but the comment box is still under my home page. I've tried removing several functions, but none seem to work.here's a screenshot of my problem : 
http://tinypic.com?ref=wmayj9
right now, I'm using wordpress codex to get the posts and others, but if anyone can tell me how to use thesis hooks to do all the job inside, that will be great. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Were you able to solve it. If you are using Thesis theme you should be using Thesis custom loop api and not wordpress codex to get the posts.
Read more about Thesis Custom Loop API [here](http://diythemes.com/thesis/rtfm/custom-loop-api/)

Comment: thanks. I solved the problem, but it's always helpful to know the other ways of doing it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried unchecking the allow comments box on the page inside the dashboard?

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes I did, but it wasn't the problem. The problem was in my code!!!